# How to sort by 2 integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numbers

I have tried many options to try and get the sort correct with no success.
using this piece of code its meant to output a fully sorted list onto winlist.txt but it only sorts by the first integer, so it doesn't sort properly.

```
def sort():
        winfile = list()
        with open ('winners.txt') as fin:
                for line in fin:
                        winfile.append(line.strip('\n'))
        winfile.sort()
        with open('SortWin.txt', 'w+') as fout:
                for winfile in winfile:
                        fout.write(winfile + '\n')
```

currently this piece code outputs:

```
11 Tom
2 Tom
20 Ben
20 Tom
21 Ben
```

But i want the sort to sort with 2 integers instead of only the first one.
so that the 2 comes above the 11

Comment: Its sorting by the first character, there are no integers in a string - you need to convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `key` argument:

```
def sort():
    winfile = list()
    with open ('winners.txt') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                    winfile.append(line.strip('\n'))
    winfile.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))
    with open('SortWin.txt', 'w+') as fout:
            for winfile in winfile:
                    fout.write(winfile + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, because its compact and i understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the lines by the first column, you have to split them first and then sort accordingly, by supplying the proper `key` to `sort()`:

```py
import operator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("to_be_sorted.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]

    sort_by_first_column = lambda line: int(operator.itemgetter(0)(line))
    data.sort(key=sort_by_first_column)

    for line in data:
        print(" ".join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your winfile , after reading from winners.txt, contains a list of strings.

That is why the sort() function sort your string alphabetically .

One way, you can split your strings into two-item tuple/list(fastest is split() into list), cast the first item into int.

Now you sort this list. The output will be list of strings by itself.

```
def get_key(pair):
    pair = pair.split()
    return int(pair[0])

def sort():
    winfile = list()
    with open ('winners.txt') as fin:
             for line in fin:
                    winfile.append(line.strip('\n'))
    winfile.sort(key = get_key)
    with open('SortWin.txt', 'w+') as fout:
            for winfile in winfile:
                    fout.write(winfile + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

because python `open` function will return some `String` object, so the number like this `"11"` but not `11`, you can convert it by `int()`, but there are easy way, use `pandas` moudle.
I assume your text is this:

```
11 Tom
2 Tom
20 Ben
20 Tom
21 Ben
```

## 1. use third-party (recommend)

first. you should install pandas, `pip install pandas`.

[pands.read_csv site](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv)

```py
import pandas as pd

# sep is Delimiter to use, default is comma
df = pd.read_csv('winners.txt', header=None, names=['num', 'name'], sep=' ', dtype={'num': int, 'name': str})
df = df.sort_index(by='num')
df.to_csv('SortWin.txt', index=False, sep=' ', header=None, mode='w+')
```

finally, the result like this

```
2 Tom
11 Tom
20 Ben
20 Tom
21 Ben
```

---

## 2. original python function solution

Don't use third-party, we can do it too.

```py
def sort():
    winfile = list()
    with open ('winners.txt') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            winfile.append(line.strip('\n'))
    winfile.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[0]))
    with open('SortWin.txt', 'w+') as fout:
        for winfile in winfile:
            fout.write(winfile + '\n')
```